# ID3DXSprite - the square looks like a rectangle

Tags: directx, sprite

I use ID3DXSprite Draw method to draw a 256x256 square texture. When I run the program in fullscreen mode everything works fine. But when I run it in windowed mode the texture doesn't look like a square anymore, but a rectangle (e.g. 237x230).

I have no idea what the problem is. Why aren't the graphics being rendered with their actual size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, when you toggle fullscreen mode you forget to [`Reset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) your swap chain. This method require to fill-in [`D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you must change some flags: windowed, format, and most important - back buffer size. Wrong size of back buffer causes your image deformation.

You may want to read [this great tutorial](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/creating-an-object-oriented-framework/) on that topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found what the problem was last night but it was too late so I didn't post it here. The problem was when I ran the program in windowed mode I used the width and the height of the window including the borders for the back buffer size. So the back buffer was a bit bigger than the window, and it was scaled to match the client size of the window. But when the application was in fullscreen mode there was no border anymore so the size of the back buffer matched the size of the window and there was no need for scaling. I had to use the client size of the window, without the borders.